# Publishing data from an array to a google spread sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, web-deployment, google-sheets-api, web-development-server

I am working on a project where I run a web page from a local server using Xampp. In the web page I have a button which when clicked produces an array of 24 elements. I want this array to be written to my online google sheet.

**My Question:**

1)Can I post data from a web page running on a local server like Xampp to an online server like google sheet?

2)If yes, then is it possible to do it with php and javascript without any jquery?

3)If it is possible please show me the right path.

I am new to web development. Please help me. Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to post data from your localhost as long as you have an internet connection.

to do such things I recommend you to read [Sheets API Guides](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)

You will also find there a sample code to write data to a spreadsheet [on this page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)

Still an API key is required for public spreadsheets for other requests you need to use OAuth 2.0 as told [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)

> If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an individual's private data), then the application must provide an OAuth
> 2.0 token with the request. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to.
>
> If the request doesn't require authorization (such as a request for public data), then the application must provide either the API key
> or an OAuth 2.0 token, or both—whatever option is most convenient for
> you.

also as an advice and if you know javascript you could use Google App Script to get Started, after validating the implementation of the library into your project and console you will find built-in functions.